# ambiguous between two completely identical functions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I tried updating an MVC3 project and now I'm getting this really strange error in one of my functions.
It looks really funny because it tells me it can distinct between two identical methods.

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>, object)' and 
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>, object)'
```

How?

Comment: More than likely this is because you're referencing both the old MVC3 dll and the new one that you upgraded to.  In your project, open up the references, and make sure that the correct version is referenced.

Comment: references are looking good (afaik), i only have a single reverence to a single system.Web.Mvc, ...

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when your Web.Config file references multiple versions of MVC.  You can probably clean that up, to get rid of the errors.

Comment: what do I have too look out for for getting a celan version?

Comment: I would just remove everything that has a version, and references MVC from your Web.config(s) (Another one in the views folder now).  Then use NuGet to get the latest version of MVC